# Why file sys/types.h doesn't contain function definition of major(dev_t dev)?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

An error is being reported when I use the function major(st_dev) in my code:
"‘major’ was not declared in this scope"

Looking up [documentation in the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/major), it suggests that the file sys/types.h contains the definition major(dev_t dev). When I check the file /usr/include/sys/types.h on Linux version 5.10.76-linuxkit, it doesn't contains definition of major(dev_t dev).

I believe the missing definition of major(dev_t dev) in the file /usr/include/sys/types.h is the source of the error.

So my question is why doesn't /usr/include/sys/types.h contains the major(dev_t dev) definition as documented in the manual page 3 entry?

```
major(3) - Linux man page
Name
makedev, major, minor - manage a device number
Synopsis
#define BSD SOURCE               /* See feature test macros(7) */
#include <sys/types.h>
dev_t makedev(int maj, int min);
unsigned int major(dev_t dev);
unsigned int minor(dev_t dev);
Description
```

[image: misc]

The code is below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>



major(statbuf.st_dev);
```

Comment: Did you read `feature_test_macros(7)` and `#define _BSD_SOURCE` before inscluding any header?

Comment: The functions will be declared by `#include <sys/types.h>` if you put `#define _BSD_SOURCE` at the top of the file and the version of glibc is less than 2.28. On Linux, you can also declare the functions using `#include <sys/sysmacros.h>` and that does not need any feature-test macros to be defined.

Comment: #include <sys/sysmacros.h> works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BSD include file <sys/types.h> originally created in 1982.

On Linux, the helper include <sys/types.h> also includes the <features.h> file. The provided function of this file has changed over time on Linux. That documentation is old, as it refers to BSD_SOURCE. In current versions, BSD_SOURCE is an alias for _DEFAULT_SOURCE.

To obtain those macros, you must include the <sys/sysmacros.h> file.